# can't send pickle object from linux to windows through sockets

Tags: python, linux, sockets, server, raspberry-pi

I can't send pickle object from raspberry with Linux through socket as a client to an online windows server while I can send it from my computer without any problem. The weird thing that I can send the message length (the server receive the message length ) but can't send the pickle object and the server is stuck to the `while` loop after receiving that message.

client code:

```
 message = pickle.dumps(faceBlob)

 message_header = bytes(f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}", "utf-8")
 client_socket.send(message_header + message)
```

server code:

```
try:

    # Receive our "header" containing message length, it's size is defined and constant
    message_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

    # If we received no data, client gracefully closed a connection, for example using socket.close() or socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    if not len(message_header):
        return False

    # Convert header to int value
    message_length = int(message_header.decode('utf-8').strip())
    fragments = []
    print(message_length)
    received_len = 0
    while received_len < message_length:


        chunk = client_socket.recv(message_length - received_len)
        if not chunk:
            break
        fragments.append(chunk)
        received_len += len(chunk)

    data_arr = b"".join(fragments)


    # Return an object of message header and message data
    return {'header': message_header, 'data': data_arr}
except:
    return False
```

Comment: `pickle` requires having the source code of non-built-in objects available so they can be unpickled.

Comment: true , it already have it , I'm asking if there is a modification in raspberry linux to make so it can send the object , because the object is sent perfectly from my pc

Comment: OK. So your question really has nothing to do with `pickle` — you're just unable to send some binary data through the socket. Just a guess, but it looks to me like the line `data_arr = b"".join(fragments)` is indented incorrectly (it should **not** be inside the `while` loop).

Comment: it's already done inn the real code .. but still raspberry dont send the array